# RANK & DENSE_RANK as aggregate(not analytic) function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, rank, dense-rank

Is there any option to use RANK/DENSE_RANK function in SQL Server as aggregate? For example the below query in Oracle/Postgres returns hypothetical ranking of the value 200 in the orders table based on the order's gross value.

```
 SELECT RANK(200) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY gross_value ASC)
   FROM orders;
```

RANK/DENSE_RANK with OVER clause works quite different(as analytic function) and that's not what I want to get.

Comment: No such built-in i think, but i guess you can emulate it with a correlated subquery: `select a,b,c, (select count(*) FROM orders o where o.gross_value < 5000) + 1 as rank, (select count(distinct gross_value) FROM orders o where o.gross_value < 5000) + 1 as denserank`

Comment: @MartinSmith exactly - I have already edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work out what the ranking would be by getting the highest rank for all values below that. If there is none then `ISNULL` it to `1`.

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(rn) + 1, 1)
FROM (
    SELECT rn = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY gross_value)
    FROM orders
    WHERE gross_value < 200
) t;
```

For descending order you do it like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(rn) + 1, 1)
FROM (
    SELECT rn = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY gross_value DESC)
    FROM orders
    WHERE gross_value > 200
) t;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Indeed, subquery seems to be the workaround for that.